# VB.NET load/save xml or txt from same path as application

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

Here is the code I use to set apppath

```
Private AppPath = Application.StartupPath
```

Here is the code i tried to open xml or txt file:

```
filename.Load(Application.StartupPath, "filename.xml")
filename.Save(Application.StartupPath, "filename.xml")
```

But it still wants to open file from C:\filename.xml?

Where is my mistake and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Private AppPath as String = Application.StartupPath
AppPath = AppPath & IIf(Mid(AppPath, Len(AppPath), 1) = "\", "", "\")
filename.Load(AppPath, "filename.xml")
```

Windows will not put your file in root of C: but in some user folder ..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what object filename is, but wouldn't

```
filename.Load("filename.xml")
```

Just work? (It does in C#)

Answer (score 0):

```
filename.Load(Application.StartupPath & "\" & "filename.xml")
```

Try it, it might work!